# Python ggplot- ggsave function not defined

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2

I've just started to learn to use python. I'm using anaconda python `3.5` and Rodeo to do a simple `ggplot`.

```
from ggplot import *
df=pd.DataFrame({"Animal":["dog","dolphin","chicken","ant","spider"],"Legs":[4,0,2,6,8]})
p=ggplot(df, aes(x="Animal", weight="Legs")) + geom_bar(fill='blue')
p
ggsave("test.png",p)
```

Everything works fine before the 5th line. I got the plot as I wanted. But I got an error when I tried to save the plot:

> NameError: name 'ggsave' is not defined

It seems that there's no ggsave function in ggplot module? The ggplot version is 0.11.1. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Use 'p.save("test.png")'

Comment: @rfkortekaas I have the same problem - your solution works, I am just not able to specify dpi and format among other things. Do you know what the solution is using ggsave? I have a NameError saying ggsave is not defined.

Comment: @Justin your question is not related to this. Please create your own.

Comment: Can you give the output of `'ggsave' in dir(ggplot)` just prior to calling `ggsave`? I _expect_ that the result will be `True`. If not, we know that the problem is in your import statement somehow, since `ggsave` is definitely an imported symbol from the `ggplot` module according to its documentation.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
p.save('test.png')
```